# Is apply all associations between entities in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am getting Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: employee, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(employeeAddresses)]. So i have two entities like

1. Employee:

   ---

   employee_id(pk),
   employee_name,
   employee_type(fk),
2. EmployeeAddress:

   ---

   employee_address_id,
   land_no,
   mobile_no,
   address_type (fk),
   employee_id  (fk)

When i am trying to apply one-to-many and many-to-one associations. I am getting above exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write down your onetomany relationship from Emoloyee entity and reverse mapping from EmployeeAddress entity

```
 class Employee
 {
    @Id
    private employee_id;

    private String employee_name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<EmployeeAddres> employeeAddress;



 }
```

and EmployeeAddres entity

```
 class EmployeeAddres
 {
      // add your other attributes (don't put employee_id attribute)

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
     private Employee employee;

 }
```

Comment: In employee:@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="employee")
 @JoinColumn(name = "employee_address_id", nullable = false)
 public Set<EmployeeAddress> getEmployeeAddresses() {
  return employeeAddresses;
 }

Comment: In EmployeeAddress entity:

Comment: @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Employee.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName="employee_id",nullable=false)
 @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
 @org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
 public Employee getEmployee() {
  return employee;
 }